# How disable scoring in elasticsearch for one query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to disable score calculation on particular query (not for type or all index) in elasticsearch?

Comment: you can simply use a filter or  [query filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html)

Comment: or use constant score query http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, you could wrap your particular query in **ConstantScoreQuery**

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "query": { your_query_here}
        "filter": {your_filter_here}
        "boost" : 1.0
    }
}
```

All matched documents will get score 1.0. For more reference information - http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html